# Cant able to Authorize one drive in deployment center of web app service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

When authorizing one drive with my web app service getting below error 'unauthorized_client: The client does not exist. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the application management site at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.'

I am trying to deploy an web app created 'index.html' file stored in onedrive and wanted to connect deployment center with one drive, checked the web app URL provided in azure it is up and running.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the steps you are following for deployment through One-drive? Also do you have any authentication set up for webapp like Single Sign on etc?

Comment: In web app services -> Deployment center -> selecting 'one drive' and on clicking authorize button I am getting above error which I have mentioned. I am not using any authentication set up. But I used another approach to get my 'index.html' file deployed

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed now. Could you please try again and update here. If it doesn't work, I would need a network trace while reproducing the issue.